# performSelector for heterogeneous items in an Array causing NSInvalidArgumentException

Tags: objective-c

My NSArray holds two different types of classes, both of which derive from NSObject and have a  method with the same name. If I call:

```
[myArrayList 
      makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(dehydrate) 
      withObject:myParamObjec];
```

I get the 'unrecognized selector' exception:

> uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '*** -[BlankItem dehydrate]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x10328e0'

If I iterate through each element of 'myArrayList' and manually invoke 'hydrate' on BlankItem as a selector, same thing but if I cast correctly, everything is okay.

```
for (id item in myArray)
{
    if ([item isKindOfClass:[BlankItem class]])
    {
        BlankItem *blankItem = (BlankItem *)item;

        // this works
        [blankItem dehydrate:connectionFactory];

        // this produces the exception
        [item performSelector:@selector(dehydrate) withObject:myParamObjec];
    }
    else
    {
        [item performSelector:@selector(dehydrate) withObject:myParamObjec];
    }
}
```

Class declarations:

```
@interface BlankItem : NSObject {   
}

- (void)hydrate:(MyParamClass *)paramClass;
@end


@interface RegularItem : NSObject { 
}

- (void)hydrate:(MyParamClass *)paramClass;
@end
```

Do the two classes, BlankItem and RegularItem need to inherit from a common BaseClass in order for this to be correct?

I don't see what I'm doing or not doing that's producing this error. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selector you want is `dehydrate:` — you're leaving off the colon, which makes it a completely different, colon-less selector. As far as Objective-C is concerned, the selectors "dehydrate" and "dehydrate:" are as different as "kill" and "skill".

Comment: d'oh! Thanks for catching that.